# Image expanding larger than parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains an image. I want the image to resize with the div, but I do not want the image to ever have a height greater than 480px. I will post what I have below. It resizes with the div correctly, but it does not obey the max-height. If I move the mx height to the img css it does, but it will not resize then. I'm sure its something simple, but I can't seem to get it.

```
.feature_image {    
    max-height:480px
}

.feature_image img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="feature_image">
        <img src="img/main-featured-image.png"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8qLeE/30/

Comment: That does not scale proportionally

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried putting a `display:block`?

Full CSS would look like:

```
.feature_image img {height: 100%; width: 100%; display:block;}
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason behind your issue is that you did not specify the `width` of the container but, in the same time, you set a `width: 100%;` for the image.

I tested this with and it works just fine:

```
.feature_image {    
    height: 480px;
    width: 480px;
}

.feature_image img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This solution is good for small images, however it causes large images to distort, but there are [solutions to overcome it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369301/css-image-scaling-to-fit-within-area-not-distort).

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify not only max-height; but also height in order to use height 100% for the image! :) CSS has no idea what 100% of to inherit. I hope you get it.

```
.feature_image {    
    max-height:480px;
    height: 480px;
}

.feature_image img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That distorts the image because with is not resized proportionally

Comment: You need to choose either portrait or landscape proportion of your images! So basically you can set height/width to a certain value and auto-resize the width/height of the image according to their propotions. There is no other option besides 'cropping' them by putting them in div container with overflow: hidden :)

Answer (score 2):

You need width:auto;

```
.feature_image img{

    max-height:480px;
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qLeE/51/